# How to change all JPEG pixels in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, jpeg

I have a project in which I capture a photo from camera (using Camera or Camera2 API) and then I have to manipulate all image pixels colors.
The image is large (4032X3024) and using Bitmap.getPixel(x,y) or Bitmap.setPixel(x,y) takes forever.

Is there a better way that I can work on the image's pixels? Is there some kind of external library I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You could get a copy of bitmap's pixels into int[] and process it by using [getPixels()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). As for some performance and memory improvements you could copy only some part of bitmap into pixels and process parts of array in separate threads. Once all finished, put together the final processed pixels and call [setPixels()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))
2. There is [a big topic](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/compute.html) that exists for this exact reason. I would probably suggest looking into it if it is applied to your app.